# Switch provider for the omniauth-shopify-oauth2 gem in runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, shopify, omniauth

The initializer for the [omniauth-shopify-oauth2](https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2) gem is supposed to look like this:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shopify, ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY'], ENV['SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET']
end
```

However, in our Rails app resides a few different brands who offers the same functionality. Throughout the entire app, the `request.domain` of a request determines which brand you are exposed to (`brand1.example.com`, `brand2.example.com`, etc.).

We can easily store brand specific credentials and redirect the users to the brand specific authorization path:

```
https://example.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=brand1&scope=read_orders,read_products&redirect_uri=https://brand1.example.com/auth/shopify/callback
```

But I can't figure out how we can have different providers for the middleware, chosen based on the visited `request.domain`. Any idea how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omniauth provides documentation on [Dynamic Providers](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers), which will be helpful here. Something like:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shopify, setup: lambda do |env|

    # Do logic to get correct credentials for request.
    # For example, if you store the credentials on a model called Brand,
    # and have it keyed on "subdomain":
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    brand = Brand.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)

    env['omniauth.strategy'].options.merge!({
      client_id: brand.client_id,
      client_secret: brand.client_secret
    })

    # `site` needs to be set. This is part of the shopify provider setup phase, which we are overriding
    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = "https://#{ request.GET['shop'] }"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for bringing my attention to dynamic providers. But I think I would need a more thorough walkthrough. Where do I put the above code, and how do I handle this on a session basis (e.g. in the controller) without changing the provider globally?

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: this code goes in the initializer and replaces the `provider` snippet that you provided in the question. The logic to get the brand-specific values then sits within the lambda, rather than in any controller (although you may want to extract this logic to a PORO for better code organisation and ease of testing). I've updated the example, which hopefully makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks @gwcodes I have tested this and it looks promising. I do however not get all the way, because an exception is raised at [lib/omniauth/strategies/shopify.rb:93](https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/shopify.rb#L89). It seems that `options[:client_options][:site]` is nil. Seems [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140266/omniauth-dynamic-client-options-site-within-the-strategy/11185382#11185382) might hold an answer to the problem, but I'm not sure?

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: try adding `site: "https://#{request.GET['shop']}"` to the hash (e.g. under `client_secret`)

Comment: Perfect, that led me in the right direction. I added these lines: `params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])` and `env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = "https://#{params['shop']}"`. And then it worked. If you agree with this, please update the answer accordingly for others to be able to use it, then I'll make sure to check the answer and release the bounty. And again, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: glad to hear you got it working. I've updated the example to reflect the final working form. BTW, does `request.GET['shop']` not work? This is what the shopify strategy is doing in the setup phase that we are overriding (see https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/shopify.rb#L27)

Comment: it propably will work then. I picked the other approach because I noticed it in my old non-dynamic implementation. But your approach i shorter. I will test it tomorrow, but the bounty is up for expiry, so I'm going ahead and releasing it now.

Comment: Your suggestion works, and it seems simpler, so feel free to update the answer accordingly.